# three.js MeshLine vertex implementation

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, vertex-shader

I'm struggling with correct vertex shader implementation for fat lines. I tried using spite/MeshLine, but it hasn't proper mitering which is a must for me. Therefore I started my own implementation (with help from https://blog.scottlogic.com/2019/11/18/drawing-lines-with-webgl.html).

```
uniform vec2 uScreen;
uniform float uWidth;

attribute vec3 next;
attribute vec3 prev;
attribute float corner;

void main()
{
  vec4 varPos = vec4(position, 1.0);
  vec4 varPrev = vec4(prev, 1.0);
  vec4 varNext = vec4(next, 1.0);
  if (all(equal(varPos.xy, varPrev.xy))) {
    varPrev.xy = varPos.xy + normalize(varPos.xy - varNext.xy);
  }
  if (all(equal(varPos.xy, varNext.xy))) {
    varNext.xy = varPos.xy + normalize(varPos.xy - varPrev.xy);
  }
  vec2 AB = normalize(normalize(varPos.xy - varPrev.xy) * uScreen);
  vec2 BC = normalize(normalize(varNext.xy - varPos.xy) * uScreen);
  vec2 tangent = normalize(AB + BC);
  vec2 miter = vec2(-tangent.y, tangent.x);
  vec2 normalA = vec2(-AB.y, AB.x);
  float miterLength = 1.0 / dot(miter, normalA);
  vec2 vertexPosition = varPos.xy + (corner * miter * uWidth * miterLength) / uScreen.xy;
  vec4 finalPosition = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.,1.);
  gl_Position =  finalPosition;
}
```

I put doubled points with next and prev vertex coords to calculate miter. Corner has [1, -1, 1, -1,...] and so on for each vertex (in order to put vertices on both sides of line).
This is what I have so far and that works correctly - I get proper miter, but I'd like to have constant line width regardless of zoom. Currently vertices are calculated in model coords, and lines get thicker when I zoom in. I'd like them to have constant width - let's say 5px no matter the zoom. I tried something similar to spite/MeshLine, but with no luck (polygons get warped and twisted).

```
  finalPosition *= projectionMatrix;
  finalPosition.xy = finalPosition.xy / ( vec4( uScreen, 0., 1. ) * projectionMatrix ).xy;
```

I also tried to transform coords to clip space first then calculate miter, but that also fails due to normalization of miter vector, and that led to values other than <-1, 1>.
I have OrthographicCamera, my use case is lots of polygons on 2D space.

Could someone explain how to achieve such effect?

btw. I tried to manually multiplicate vertex by view matrix then projection matrix and I ended up with vectors like (0.0303837, -0.0236054, -0.5, -164978.). I don't understand, why w is so big? When calculations are performed automatically w is always 1 (i tried to set it to other values manually).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with following solution:

```
  float sizeAttenuation = 1. / (projectionMatrix[0][0] * 5000.);
  float miterLength = sizeAttenuation / dot(miter, normalA);
```

but it feels little hacky and hardcoded. I bet that there is better way to do this.